# Create multiple dictionaries from a single iterator in nested for loops

Tags: python

I have a nested list comprehension which has created a list of six lists of ~29,000 items. I'm trying to parse this list of final data, and create six separate dictionaries from it. Right now the code is very unpythonic, I need the right statement to properly accomplish the following:

1.) Create six dictionaries from a single statement.

2.) Scale to any length list, i.e., not hardcoding a counter shown as is.

I've run into multiple issues, and have tried the following:

1.) Using while loops

2.) Using break statements, will break out of the inner most loop, but then does not properly create other dictionaries. Also break statements set by a binary switch.

3.) if, else conditions for n number of indices, indices iterate from 1-29,000, then repeat.

Note the ellipses designate code omitted for brevity.

```
# Parse csv files for samples, creating a dictionary of key, value pairs and multiple lists.
with open('genes_1') as f:
    cread_1 = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter = '\t'))
    sample_1_values = [j for i, j in (sorted([x for x in {i: float(j) 
                        for i, j in cread_1}.items()], key = lambda v: v[1]))]
    sample_1_genes = [i for i, j in (sorted([x for x in {i: float(j) 
                            for i, j in cread_1}.items()], key = lambda v: v[1]))]

... 

# Compute row means.
mean_values = []
for i, (a, b, c, d, e, f) in enumerate(zip(sample_1_values, sample_2_values, sample_3_values, sample_4_values, sample_5_values, sample_6_values)):
    mean_values.append((a + b + c + d + e + f)/6)

# Provide proper gene names for mean values and replace original data values by corresponding means.
sample_genes_list = [i for i in sample_1_genes, sample_2_genes, sample_3_genes, sample_4_genes, sample_5_genes, sample_6_genes]

sample_final_list = [sorted(zip(sg, mean_values)) for sg in sample_genes_list]

# Create multiple dictionaries from normalized values for each dataset.
class BreakIt(Exception): pass
try: 
    count = 1         
    for index, items in enumerate(sample_final_list):
        sample_1_dict_normalized = {}             
        for index, (genes, values) in enumerate(items):
            sample_1_dict_normalized[genes] = values
            count = count + 1
            if count == 29595:
                raise BreakIt
except BreakIt:
    pass
```

...

```
try: 
    count = 1         
    for index, items in enumerate(sample_final_list):
        sample_6_dict_normalized = {}             
        for index, (genes, values) in enumerate(items):
            if count > 147975:
                sample_6_dict_normalized[genes] = values
            count = count + 1
            if count == 177570:
                raise BreakIt
except BreakIt:
    pass

# Pull expression values to qualify overexpressed proteins.
print 'ERG values:'
print 'Sample 1:', round(sample_1_dict_normalized.get('ERG'), 3) 
print 'Sample 6:', round(sample_6_dict_normalized.get('ERG'), 3)
```

Comment: I said this before: don't create separate `sample_x_...` variables when you could use lists instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is too long for me to give exact answer. I will answer very generally.

First, you are using `enumerate` for no reason. if you don't need *both* index and value, you probably don't need enumerate.

This part:

```
with open('genes.csv') as f:
    cread_1 = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter = '\t'))
    sample_1_dict = {i: float(j) for i, j in cread_1}
    sample_1_list = [x for x in sample_1_dict.items()]
    sample_1_values_sorted = sorted(sample_1_list, key=lambda expvalues: expvalues[1])
    sample_1_genes = [i for i, j in sample_1_values_sorted]
    sample_1_values = [j for i, j in sample_1_values_sorted]
    sample_1_graph_raw = [float(j) for i, j in cread_1]
```

should be (a) using a `list` named `samples` and (b) much shorter, since you don't really need to extract all this information from `sample_1_dict` and move it around right now. It can be something like:

```
samples = [None] * 6
for k in range(6):
    with open('genes.csv') as f: #but something specific to k
        cread = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter = '\t'))
        samples[k] = {i: float(j) for i, j in cread}
```

after that, calculating the sum and mean will be way more natural.

In this part:

```
class BreakIt(Exception): pass
try: 
    count = 1         
    for index, items in enumerate(sample_final_list):
        sample_1_dict_normalized = {}             
        for index, (genes, values) in enumerate(items):
            sample_1_dict_normalized[genes] = values
            count = count + 1
            if count == 29595:
                raise BreakIt
except BreakIt:
    pass
```

you should be (a) iterating of the `samples` list mentioned earlier, and (b) not using `count` at all, since you can iterate naturally over `samples` or `sample[i].list` or something like that.

Comment: Enumerate is used because unpacking of any list of lists would give a value error otherwise. The first code block has been modified. I would need a file open list, a sample name list, and a way for each cread object to be able to be used outside the local scope of a function definition to replace each dataset code block with a single function that is called later.

Comment: really, all you need is the list of oredered `items()`. everything else can be extracted from it when needed. The unpacking is not a good idea; you can use lists and list-comprehension and a `sum()` instead.

Comment: Count is used is the workaround as the iterating over the list of lists will restart the index count used by enumerate, as in the question, count was the last resort because I couldn't get the correct or desired code using while loops and breaks, other methods, etc.

Comment: I've flagged for moderation to delete until I reform the initial code block, which is itself another topic for another question. As is, this question should have been given as an example of how to control index operations within nested for loops, along with more specifics to show my exact issue besides the other issues mentioned.

Comment: OK. exception is one way for breaking out of nested loops. better way to put it inside a function and use `return`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several problems. You should put your code in functions that preferably do one thing each. Than you can call a function for each sample without repeating the same code six times (I assume that is what the ellipsis is hiding.). Give each function a self-describing name and a doc string that explains what it does. There is quite a bit unnecessary code. Some of this might become obvious once you have it in functions. Since functions take arguments you can hand in your 29595, for example.